# Inno Setup remove or edit Installing Application Name display on shut down

Tags: inno-setup

When running an Inno Setup compiled executable, if you try and shut down Windows the 'Programs still need to close' screen is displayed listing the running applications. This shows the Inno Setup Application Name of the compiled executable with '(Waiting for) in front of it and then below that it in smaller font it shows 'Installing Application Name.'

[image: Shut down installing message]

Is it possible to remove or edit the 'Installing' prefix or simply totally remove or hide the second line of text? If so, how can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Handling and customizing errors and messages in Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65980371/850848).

This particular message is defined by the `ShutdownBlockReasonInstallingApp` message.

You can change it in the [`[Messages]` section](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=messagessection):

```
[Messages]
ShutdownBlockReasonInstallingApp=Installing %1.
```

Comment: Thanks Martin. Should have thought to look there!